# Paypal Authorization & Tokenzation

Tags: paypal, authorization, tokenize

i need to save credit card & do below process

1- Initialize pass CC number,Cvv,Exp Date + additional params to Paypal.
2- Receive Unique CC card reference number.
3- before or after do Authorization & Void Authorization to verify Valid Credit card.
4- initize New payment debit process used by Unique CC Reference number without asking CVV.

Please give idea & Suitable Example

Thanks

Comment: are you PCI compliant ?

Comment: I was used to finish above progress used by below url  https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/vault/credit-cards/ https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment   it's working fine & good,  But Auth not in this valut method,  How i validate Credit card valid or not valid  using paypal?